# in GAE Python, I can not delete cookies locally, but on the web if I can

Tags: python, google-app-engine, cookies

I'm working on a project, working directly on the web, but for speed of development, I decided to spend my project locally, but when I want to delete a cookie locally I can not, be the same code that is on the web

```
c = Cookie.SimpleCookie(os.environ["HTTP_COOKIE"])  
c["MyCookie"]=""
c["MyCookie"]["expires"] = cookie_expiry_date(-20)
self.response.headers.add_header("Set-Cookie",c.output(header=''))
```

I try this

```
self.response.headers.add_header("Set-Cookie",'MyCookie=""; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:00 GMT')
```

But it does not work

Comment: "It does not work" is spectacularly unhelpful. What _does_ happen? Have you used your browser's dev tools to examine the responses and compare production to development? What differs?

Answer (score 3):

If you are using webapp2, You can manage cookies very simply (in local `dev_appserver` too):

```
# Deletes a cookie previously set in the client.
response.delete_cookie('bad_cookie')
```

here's the [docs](http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/guide/response.html#setting-cookies)

Comment: thanks, helped me a lot.
an apology for the English, I'm a newbie learning

Answer (score -2):

You can use Chrome developer Tools. Under menu resources you find and delete your cookies